# It's possible to block an url path with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Currently i'm getting a DDoS attack directly to this URL: myserver.com/?task=randompost, the "?task=randompost" doesnt exist anymore so they get redirected to the home webpage. Considering that they are attacking directly to that url path, its there any way to block all users that tries to enter that path??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with **mod_rewrite:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =task=randompost
RewriteRule ^$ - [F,L]
```

This will ONLY work for `example.com/?task=randompost` request (will not work for `example.com/index.php?task=randompost`) and it needs to be placed in .`htaccess` somewhere at the top (before any other rewrite rules). If placed in virtual host context, the `^$` needs to be replaced by `^/$`.

The `[F]` flag will instruct Apache to return 403 error immediately.